# Query decryption data SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, node-crypto

It would like me know if, exists a native tool of the SQL SERVER for encryption some fields, put when making and execute a query, the SQL SERVER decrypt automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's called **Transparent Data Encryption** (TDE).

Here is the official MSDN intro:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Note this criteria (emphasis mine):

> a native tool of the SQL SERVER for encryption [of] **some fields**

TDE works at the *page level*, which means you have to use it for all of the fields in a table. If it's important that some fields not be encrypted, you have to accomplish this by putting them into a different table with a 1-to-1 relationship.